# Using CSS tables but allocating a pixel based width to a table cell

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a kind of table in CSS.

My aim is to have 2 sections, the brand and the rest of the topbar in this case.

What I would like to do is split it in to 2 main pieces, so I'll have the brand logo on the left spanning over `100px` and then the rest of the space will be allocated to the navigation. In the navigation I will split it into 2 lists which one could be floated left, and the other right.

However, I'm struggling to get the brand section to consist of `100px` in width whilst having `display: table-cell;`

I have attached a fiddle with my current work.

You will see that the brand section currently spans the entire width rather than the desired `100px`

Please note that the section on the right of the brand needs to be the remaining width of the browser. To visually show this I have a screenshot below.

[image]

Everything in the white section would be 1 div spanning the entire width on the right of the dark grey brand area, I don't think i can do this using `display: inline-block;` as it wouldn't take up the remaining space.

Can anyone guide me further please.

http://jsfiddle.net/jyosndj3/1/

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm not sure I would have taken that approach.  You're thinking about it too much as a table in the sense of old school HTML page formatting, even though your desired output isn't particularly tabular and can be achieved with pretty standard modern CSS.  Look into `display: inline-block;`, for one.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to use display inline block, but i want to have the brand section then a second section that takes up the entire remaining width, this way I can float an element left and another one right within it. How can I do this without table layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, there's more than one way to skin a cat.  Like I mentioned in my comment above, I don't know that I would have taken the table approach, personally.  Here's one of many, many ways you could do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/jyosndj3/2/

## CSS:

```
.topbar {
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
background-color: #777;
overflow: hidden;
}

.logo {
float: left;
width: 100px;
height: 30px;
background-color: #111;
}

.left {
float: left;
width: 50%;
margin-right: -50px;
padding-right: -50px;
height: 30px;
background-color: #f00;
}

.right {
float: left;
width: 50%;
margin-right: -50px;
padding-right: -50px;
height: 30px;
background-color: #00f;
}
```

## HTML:

```
<div class="topbar">
    <div class="topbar-contents">
        <div class="logo">
Logo
        </div>
        <div class="left">
Left
        </div>
        <div class="right">
Right
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Quite frankly, I wouldn't use this exact code in production, as it's just a quick proof of concept, but hopefully it at least gets you thinking a bit more outside the box with your approach.

Comment: But if I floated content below that, it would throw itself into the wrong place. I would presume I would need the clear the floated elements. Which element would I apply that too?

Comment: Correct.  It depends on what method you're using to clear floated elements on your project, but it could be as simple as following up the topbar with a `<br style="clear: both;" />`

Comment: Isn't doing that with a br a really messy method? could we not have a topbar:after { clear: both; } or would that not work?

Comment: Yes it is messy, but was just an example.  Trying to address a problem like this by thinking of it as a table is a really messy approach ;-)  The method you're referring to should work for your needs.  It all depends on what code follows, else I'd suggest a better option.

Comment: Resolved all, thank you very much. I actually used an entirely different approach, similar in it's ways. But this was the inspiration that made me remember how i've done this in the past :)

Comment: Perfect!  I was just typing up a response.  I wasn't necessarily hoping to provide an exact solution, but just wanted to get you thinking differently than the approach you were trying to take.    Glad you got it worked out!

Comment: Thank you for the effort anyway :) much appreciated.